# VALID_ARCHS = arm64 armv7 armv7s not generating any armv7s

Tags: ios, architecture, armv7

I'm having a question about the compilation on iOS. I'm generating a framework and it used to generate arm64, armv7 and armv7s (+ simulators with lipo and fun).

The thing is, armv7s is not present in the binary anymore.

Architectures in the fat file are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64

But I clearly asks in my XCConfig for VALID_ARCHS = arm64 armv7 armv7s. I verified that the XCConfig was indeed used and not overridden.

I tried various google search but most of the time we find people not understanding why their app is not compiling with the wrong version of the lib.

So now, I'm coming here, the last chance to understand why no armv7s lib is being created for my framework. Maybe it's as simple as "it's not possible anymore".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode has dropped support for `armv7s` since XCode 6 I think, the `${ARCHS_STANDARD}` now only include `armv7, arm64` and simulator will include `i386, x86_64`, so your fat static library/framework will only include them.

To support `armv7s`, add it under `${ARCHS_STANDARD}` in `Architectures` field and build again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew it was removed from the ${ARCHS_STANDARD}, but somehow I ended up thinking that ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = no + VALID_ARCHS = arm64 armv7 armv7s were enough.

Comment: I think we can safely drop support for `armv7s` also, it shouldn't be any problem since XCode have long dropped support for it

Comment: I would think so too, but in the case of one of my client asking for it, I wanted to be sure to have it. (One of them tested the binary for bitcode against armv7s lately :p)